# Object is undefined on event listener callback passed as a method in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular 2 and typescript, in my project I have created tables dynamically and appended to board DIV. I have given addEventLister to the table and passing callback as a method. But whenever an event is triggered the, but the object(this.diamondSet in below code) is giving undefined. I couldn't find what I did wrong

Please help me to find the error, Thanks in advance,

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  board_row: number = 8;
  board_col: number = 8;
  cellNum: number = 0;
  cellCordinates: Object = {};
  diamond_count: number = 8;
  diamondSet: Object = {};
  winCount: number = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
   this.randomGenerators();
    this.initializeBoard();
    }

    initializeBoard() {
    let table = document.createElement("table");
    table.id = "diamond_container";
    for (let i = 0; i < this.board_row; i++) {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        for (let j = 0; j < this.board_col; j++) {
            let td = document.createElement('td');
            this.cellCordinates[this.cellNum] = {
                x: i,
                y: j
            };
            td.className = "cell unknown";
            td.id = `${this.cellNum}`;
            this.cellNum++;
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    document.getElementById("board").appendChild(table);
    document.getElementById("diamond_container").addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
}
randomGenerators() {
    while (Object.keys(this.diamondSet).length < this.diamond_count) {
        let randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 63)
        this.diamondSet[randomnumber] = randomnumber;
    }
}
clickHandler(e) {
 console.log("handru");
 if (Object.keys(this.diamondSet).length) {
        if (e.target.nodeName == 'TD') {
            this.winCount++;
            console.log("before")
            if (this.diamondSet[e.target.id]) {
                e.target.className = "cell diamond disabled";
                delete this.diamondSet[e.target.id];
               
            } else {
                var slope = this.hint(e.target.id);
                $('td').removeClass('arrow');
                e.target.className = "cell arrow disabled";
                e.target.style["boxShadow"] = 'none';
                e.target.style["transform"] = "rotate(" + slope + "deg)";
            }
        }
    } 
}

minDistance(clicked_id) {
    var distanceMap = {};
    Object.keys(this.diamondSet).map((id) => {
        distanceMap[id] = Math.abs(this.cellCordinates[clicked_id].x - this.cellCordinates[id].x) + Math.abs(this.cellCordinates[clicked_id].y - this.cellCordinates[id].y);
    });
    return Object.keys(distanceMap).sort(function(a, b) {
        return distanceMap[a] - distanceMap[b]
    })[0];
}

hint(clicked_id) {
    let nearestDiamondId = this.minDistance(clicked_id);
    return (Math.atan2((this.cellCordinates[nearestDiamondId].x - this.cellCordinates[clicked_id].x), (this.cellCordinates[nearestDiamondId].y - this.cellCordinates[clicked_id].y))) * 180 / Math.PI;
}
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <center>
    <h1>
      Diamond Sweeper
    </h1>
  </center>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="board">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are mixing up dom and angular without using `ElementRef`, this is not a good practise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @Abr001am , what am I supposed to do, make it work??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you add the eventListener with .addEventListener(), the this context is the Element itself, not your component.

You can fix this easily by using arrow function:

```
clickHandler = (e) => {
    ... // your function code here
}
```

Comment: You saved me tons of working hours! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to bind the non-arrow function with your component.

```
clickHandlerUnbinded(e)  {
   ... // your function code here
}

clickHandler = this.clickHandlerUnbinded.bind(this); // this -> is your component

document.getElementById("diamond_container").addEventListener("click", this.clickHandler);
```

Now you got a `clickHandler` with its `this` context bound to your component.

**Using arrow function is more elegant obviously.**